# Get unobfuscated source from browser after click

Tags: firefox, deobfuscation

A webpage has some contents obfuscated in some sophisticated way (at least for me). I'm unable to decipher it from the page source. Anyway, when clicking a link on a page, an onclick java function gets called and the page becomes readable. At that point, also the generated source in the browser is readable.

Is there a programming tool (like mechanize or sth., preferrably perl) that would load a page in Firefox, click the link and then get the unchipered html?

Any suggestions how to attack this problem?

Comment: Is this dealing with a Java applet?

Comment: I don't think so. The call looks like "onclick="qc.pA('FrontEndForm', 'PEditionV2c12', 'QClickEvent', '15731c4127a96e4111ee4eb5af51575504', 'WaitIcon'); return false;"" but I am not successfull in finding the definition of this function anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Chrome and check the deobfuscate source option, in the developer tools, javascript viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to view the deobfuscated code.

When you view source, browsers will show you the *original* source, not the current DOM. When you view source with Firebug, it will show you the current source, which will be what your browser is currently showing.

This approach will only work if you want to see the HTML, and not if you need programmatic extraction.

Comment: Yes, I saw the text I want to extract from the page in Firebug and with WebDeveloper plugin (View Generated Source). Now the hard part is to extract the HTML by a script.

Answer (score 0):

Try the greasemonkey add-on for firefox.

You can write a little javascript function that clicks that button for you, e.g. each time you load the page in Firefox. Check out userscripts.org to get started.

This would work (inside your browser) only for a single client and that is you .

If you need it fully automated, you can try to record a Selenium testcase. You can use another Firefox Add-On, "Selenium IDE" for this (Microsoft Office veterans would call this a "Macro Recorder") and even convert your recorded testcase to Perl code.

(Running the testcase would require to start up another little component, selenium rc (a java-based server) which would start up firefox for you and click the link.

Comment: Thanks for the Selenium idea, I will take a look.